# How can I input the data to neuroph studio?

Tags: neural-network

I am trying to train the neural network with .cvs format data but while loading the file there is an error saying bad number format in the dataset file. I also normalized the file. what can I do???? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey there may be hidden characters you can't see in your file.

1. if you have Open/Libre office open the .csv file in that.
2. Then save it as a new file but make sure to tick the box "edit filter settings"
3. It will ask you if you what "Character set" you want to use, try selecting different ones, i used "Western ASCII" and save it.
4. Open it in a notepad like app and you will probably see lots of "?"'s next to numbers.

Once i deleted those non numbers the data became usable.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the file cvs with the notepad and choose: Save as.
2. In the coding part you must choose: ANSI

Answer (score 0):

I solved this task just removing the headers line.